# Multiple input lines creating an array of data to MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, forms, object, database

So it's my another time I am going through some constant head scratching over some issue.
Here's the code:

```
adminForm: function(){
  var div = document.getElementById('main');
  var form = document.createElement('form');
  form.action = "/api/players";
  this.createInput(form, "question", "text", "question", "Your question: ", "50");
  this.createInput(form, "option", "text", "option", "A:", "20");
  this.createInput(form, "option", "text", "option", "B:", "20");
  this.createInput(form, "option","text", "option", "C:", "20");
  this.createInput(form, "option", "text", "option", "D:", "20");
  this.createInput(form, "correct", "text", "correct", "Correct Answer", "20");
  this.createInput(form, "category", "text", "category", "Category", "20");

var allAnswers = function(){
  var values = [];
  var arr = document.getElementsByClassName('option');
  for(var element of arr){
    e.target.option.value;
  }
}

form.onsubmit = function(e){

  e.preventDefault();
  var newQuestion = {
    questionString: e.target.question.value,
    possibleAnswers: allAnswers(),
    correctAnswer: e.target.correct.value,
    category: e.target.category.value
  }

  var allQuestions = new Questions();
  allQuestions.add(newQuestion, function(data){
    console.log(data);
  })
}
```

my intention is to get the values from all the inputs with the "option" class (class is under the second attribute of the createInput)and pack them up in one array that is the value of my "possibleAnswers" key in my question object. So far, instead of that I get this...

Proper object

```
{
"_id": "58b20884f001b3aecec5c580",
"questionString": "A hitman was hired to dash the Olympic dreams of         which athlete?",
"possibleAnswers": [
  "Tonya Harding",
  "Kristi Yamaguchi",
  "Jennifer Capriati",
  "Nancy Kerrigan"
],
  "category": "Sport",
  "correctAnswer": "Nancy Kerrigan"
},
```

and the wrong one

```
 {
 "_id": "58b208e5556cd0fda30d99a5",
 "questionString": "What's your name?",
 "correctAnswer": "Bree",
 "category": "general",
 "possibleAnswers": {}
 }
```